# I built an rails environment with Docker, but there is no rails file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, docker, docker-compose

I built an environment using "[Docker official rails quickstart](https://docs.docker.com/compose/rails/)". There's no error.

And the terminal shows that the app, bin, and db directories have been created, but they aren't.

```
% docker-compose run web rails new . --force --no-deps --database=postgresql
Starting root_db_1 ... done
       exist  
      create  README.md
      create  Rakefile
      create  .ruby-version
      create  config.ru
      create  .gitignore
       force  Gemfile
         run  git init from "."
Initialized empty Git repository in /myapp/.git/
      create  package.json
      create  app
      create  app/assets/config/manifest.js
      create  app/assets/javascripts/application.js
      create  app/assets/javascripts/cable.js

 ..........
         run  bundle exec spring binstub --all
* bin/rake: Spring inserted
* bin/rails: Spring inserted

%
```

```
app-directory% ls
Dockerfile              Gemfile.lock            entrypoint.sh
Gemfile                 docker-compose.yml      src
```

I tried several times to run

```
docker-compose run web rails new . --force --no-deps --database=postgresql
```

but nothing's changed.

My Ruby version is 2.6.3 and Rails version is 6.0.3, and I use MacOS.

What should I do to solve this problem??

Comment: If the code says the directories were created, then they were created, you're just not looking in the right place. You haven't told us enough to do anything except guess at the cause and solution.

Comment: Also, SO frowns on emoji in questions, comments and answers. If they are necessary in code or as characters in code, or to discuss the code or character processing, then they OK, but not in regular text. Search the [meta] site for "emoji" to find out the concensus.

Comment: From now on, I care about about using emoji.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume *app-directory* is a local directory.
If so, double check if you have mounted your local directory to the web container in the *docker-compose.yml* with

```
volumes:
  - .:/myapp
```

Otherwise the files are only created within the docker container.

Comment: This problem was resolved thanks to your advise! Thanks.